# How to get jquery multiselect to show comma delimited string values in "selectedText"?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I'm using the following [jquery multiselect plugin](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/) ... How can set the "selectedText" as a comma delimited string representation of the selected values?  That is, if "Option 1" and "Option 2" are selected then the control would render with "Option 1, Option 2" in the ListBox contents.

Comment: This sounds fairly simple, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you mean: http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#selectedlist See following for more details: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Comment: Doh, I didn't not see that in the docs. I appreciate the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the selectedList option when using the plugin. Refer below code:

```
$("#options").multiselect({

noneSelectedText:'Select a Option',
selectedList: 4   
});
```